# Unable to get and display grandchild relationship for dynamic menu in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, menu, relationship, parent-child

I am creating dynamic multilevel menu in laravel, I am able to get parent and child relationship and display the menu but unable to get and display if relationship goes one more level down.

Please assist.

My Model:

```php
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Menu', 'parent_id');
}

public function gchildren()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Menu', 'parent_id');
}
```

My Nav View:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  @foreach($menus as $menuItem)
    @if( $menuItem->parent_id == 0 )
      <li class="nav-item p-relative">
        <a class ="nav-link" href="{{ $menuItem->children->isEmpty() ? $menuItem->url : "#" }}">
          {{ $menuItem->title }}
          @if( ! $menuItem->children->isEmpty() )
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
          @endif
        </a>
        @if( ! $menuItem->children->isEmpty() )
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach($menuItem->children as $subMenuItem)
              @if( ! $subMenuItem->status == 0 )
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ $subMenuItem->url }}">{{ $subMenuItem->title }}</a>
                  @if( ! $menuItem->gchildren->isEmpty() )
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      @foreach($menuItem->gchildren as $gchildItem)
                        @if( ! $gchildItem->status == 0 )
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ $gchildItem->url }}">{{ $gchildItem->title }}</a>
                          </li>
                        @endif
                      @endforeach
                    </ul>
                  @endif
                </li>
              @endif
            @endforeach
          </ul>
        @endif
      </li>
    @endif
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

This is what I am getting:

[image: MenuImage1]

There should not be a next dropdown in above image.

In My DB there are Only 2 entries for parent ID 3 which is already a parent

[image: db image]

[image: MenuImage2]

[image: MenuImage3]

Comment: The relationships `children` and `gchildren` are defined exactly the same way. Of course the submenus are repeating

Comment: Extract the blade template which renders the children in a partial view. You can thenn call the partial view recursively as long as children are available.

Comment: What should gchildren function should have in this situation?

Comment: only 3 levels or N number of levels ?

Comment: If you don't want to change your database design, use the `level` attribute in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue.
Thanks all for you comments.

Removed `gchildren` function and changed code in nav view to this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 @foreach($menuItem->children as $subMenuItem)
  @if( ! $subMenuItem->status == 0 )
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ $subMenuItem->url }}">{{ $subMenuItem->title }}</a>
    @if( ! $subMenuItem->children->isEmpty() )
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      @foreach($subMenuItem->children as $childItem)
       @if( ! $childItem->status == 0 )
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ $childItem->url }}">{{ $childItem->title }}</a></li>
       @endif
      @endforeach
     </ul>
    @endif
   </li>
  @endif
 @endforeach
</ul>
```